# menu in App.html won't work with firebase Ionic 3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I have the menu html declared in the app.html as follows:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" *ngIf="userData">
    <ion-header>
        <div class="menu heading">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menuClose (click)="profilePage()">
                    <ion-avatar item-start>
                        <img [src]="userData.img">
                    </ion-avatar>
                    <h2 class="text-white text-shadow"><strong>{{userData.name}}</strong></h2>
                    <p class="text-white text-shadow" (click)="profilePage()">View Profile</p>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </div>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content class="menu" padding>
        <ion-list>
...
...
...
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

The problem is the variable `userData` comes from **firebase**, so when i login and go to homepage it doesn't work but once i refresh the page it works.

This is how I get `userdata` in **app.component.ts** :

```
  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, 
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    keyboard: Keyboard,
    public angularDb:AngularFireDatabase,
    public dataProvider: DataProvider
  ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log("ready")

      this.dataProvider.getData('userData').then((data)=>{

        let userData = <any>data;
        this.userData = userData;
....
```

In IONIC 4 i saw there is a possibility to create the menu in a separate page like menu.page.html and its menu.ts where the UserData can be fetched, since the app.component.ts executes only once and ionic 3 recommends implementing the menu there unfortunately there is practically no solution for this, any advice?